# How to get the value of a text field in Magento then display it in Email template

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.9

we are using magento, we need to get the value of a text field in register page to be displayed in the email template sent as a notification. the field is added by marketplace extension. it is text field.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Find the below controller sample code for send parameter to email.

```
  if(isset($_POST))
  {
    $email_template_variables = array(
       'customer_name' => $_POST['name']                 
    );

    $processedTemplate = $emailTemplate->getProcessedTemplate($email_template_variables);
```

Display varible / parameter in email like below.

```
{{var customer_name}}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply,  where to add the code of post, while  the field i want to display its value in email template is Seller url text field  in Registration page for seller this added by webkul marketplace.

Comment: For display value in transaction email, you need to follow below steps. System->Transaction Email->select your email template and add your variable value in email content. like this. {{var seller_url}} for your reference i have added screenshot above.

Comment: Thanks  but i ask about this code    if(isset($_POST))
  {
    $email_template_variables = array(
       'customer_name' => $_POST['name']                 
    );

    $processedTemplate = $emailTemplate->getProcessedTemplate($email_template_variables);                                 if the field is in regisetr.phtml

Comment: You need to add post code in controller file. Basically form present in phtml file and submit forms to controller action with post data.